# Plotting Relative abundance in r: problem with scale not matching to 100%

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot to plot the relative abundance of microbiome data.
my problem is that the y axis is shown more than 100 (i.e. 150 or 80)

here is the code I used to get relative abundance:
#Limiting data to top 100 taxa based on abundance then using transform_sample_counts.

```
top100 <-names(sort(taxa_sums(ps_oral), decreasing=TRUE)) [1:100]
ps_oral_top100 <- prune_taxa(top100, ps_oral)
ntaxa(ps_oral_top100)
ps_oral_ra = transform_sample_counts(ps_oral_top100, function(x){x / sum(x)})
```

Here is the code I used to plot:

```
ggplot(data = psmelt(ps_oral_ra), mapping = aes(x= GroupDay, y= Abundance, color= Phylum, fill= Phylum )) + geom_col()+  labs(x = "", y = "Relative Abundance\n")+theme_classic() # Relative abundance using the ps_oral_ra. At Phylum level. 

ggplot(data = psmelt(ps_oral_ra), mapping = aes(x= GroupDay, y= Abundance, color= Genus, fill= Genus )) + geom_col() +theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+  labs(x = "", y = "Relative Abundance\n") # Relative abundance using the ps_oral_ra. At Genus level.
```

Another question is how can I limit Genus to the top 20 or 10 only?

Thank you for the help.

for a reproducible example:
I used dput(sample_data(ps_oral)) [1:10, 1:6],

Sample Data:        [10 samples by 6 sample variables]:
Lane Salivette MasterID Day     Group GroupDay
X1.30031_S31     L2         1    30031 Pre Probiotic Baseline
X10.3012_S167    L2        10     3012 Pre Probiotic Baseline
X100.3109_S46    L2       100     3109 Pre   Placebo Baseline
X101.3110_S43    L1       101     3110 Pre Probiotic Baseline
X102.3111_S64    L1       102     3111 Pre   Placebo Baseline
X103.3112_S119   L2       103     3112 Pre   Placebo Baseline
X104.3114_S115   L2       104     3114 Pre Probiotic Baseline
X105.3115_S119   L1       105     3115 Pre Probiotic Baseline
X106.3116_S143   L2       106     3116 Pre   Placebo Baseline
X107.3117_S184   L2       107     3117 Pre   Placebo Baseline

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky to fix without having sample data, but you can probably add:

```
ggplot [...] + [...] +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100))
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, when I add that I get: Warning message:
Removed 10923 rows containing missing values (geom_col).  and the bars don’t all reach 100 to represent relative abundance. For sample data, I have three groups in the "GroupDay". Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide us with a reproducible [minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example) that we can copy and paste to better understand the issue and test possible solutions. You can share datasets with `dput(YOUR_DATASET)` or smaller samples with `dput(head(YOUR_DATASET))`. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610) for some great advice.)

Comment: I added a reproducible example, thank you